# How to add the contents in the beginning of a chapter

Tags: table-of-contents

I hope to add the contents in the beginning of a chapter. This is an example:

[image]

Thank you !!

Comment: Package etoc can do it.

Comment: Or the package `minitoc`?

Comment: @PaulStanley How to use the package `minitoc`? Thanks

Comment: I prefer etoc over minitoc. It is more flexible. Minitoc has some small glitches.

Comment: @Johannes_B how to use etoc? Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables_of_Contents_and_Lists_of_Figures#A_table_of_contents_for_each_chapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (as comments have noted) a number of possible ways to do this. One is the `minitoc` package. Basically it picks up entries from the table of contents. The minimal use involves

- `\usepackage{minitoc}`
- add `\tableofcontents` or `\faketableofcontents` for the whole document
- add `\dominitoc` to prepare the minitocs
- add `\minitoc` in each chapter where you want it printed

Code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\begin{document}
\dominitoc% <-- Get it ready
\tableofcontents%<-- or \faketableofcontents if you don't actually want one
\chapter{Blah}
\minitoc
\section{Blah blah}
\section{Blah blah blah}
\section{Foo! Bah!}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As always, `texdoc minitoc` is your best friend. The documentation is good.